# hmtl url button in django doesn't find my url ' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)$/$']'

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to build a button in django1 to send me the PK to my view but isn't working at all.
I'm in a screen displaying mi data, without the button everything works well, my array of objects shows the data but when I add the button it crashes

**html**

```
{% if alumnos %}
    <ul>
    {% for alumno in alumnos %}
    <td>{{ alumno.dni }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.apellido1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.apellido2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.repetidor }}</td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'edit' pk=alumno.dni %}">Editar</a>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$/$', views.edit_alumno3,name='edit'),
```

view.py

```
def edit_alumno3(request, pk):
    user = Alumno.objects.get(dni=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AlumnoForm2(instance=user)
    else:
        form = AlumnoForm2(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('edit.html', {'form': form})

    return render(request, '/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**model.py**

```
class Alumno(models.Model):
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apellido1 = models.CharField('Primer apellido',max_length=50)
    apellido2 = models.CharField('Segundo apellido',max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField("Correo electronico",null=True)
    repetidor = models.BooleanField()
    curs = models.ManyToManyField(Curso, blank=True, related_name="Historico_de_cursos")
    Nivel = models.ManyToManyField('Nivel', through = 'Completado',through_fields=('Alumno','Nivel'))
    Practica = models.ManyToManyField('Practica', through = 'Nota',through_fields=('Alumno','Practica'))
    Curso = models.ManyToManyField('Curso',through = 'Curso_alumno',through_fields=('Alumno','Curso'))


    def __str__(self):
        return self.dni
```

**the error:**

```
NoReverseMatch at /mostrar_alumnos2/

Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)$/$']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHPUq.png)

Comment: First: 
<td><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'edit' pk=alumno.dni %}">Editar</a</tr>
end it with a </td> tag. But that might not be the problem just noticed it

Comment: Can you try href="{% url 'edit' alumno.dni %}" without pk=. And also in your urls can you try url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.edit_alumno3,name='edit'),

Comment: @DaminiGanesh if i make this django doesn't find the template

Comment: which did you try? removing the "pk=" from url? also your template name is edit.html right?

Comment: @DaminiGanesh yes, my template is edit.html I tryed this but now is unable to find the template

Comment: Hmm I am not sure now.. One last try is to add template_name = 'app/edit.html' in your view.

Comment: @Victor I think there is also a problem with the directory structure of your templates. Please refer the basics of django and how it's templates work.